How to reuse AuthToken in typescript-wallet-sdk
After completing the SEP-10 authentication process using the @stellar/typescript-wallet-sdk, I obtained an AuthToken with a JWT that is valid for one day, as defined by the Anchor. I intend to reuse this AuthToken for subsequent operations with the Anchor during its validity period.
However, when attempting to utilize the AuthToken.from() method, I encountered the following error:
Error: Cannot find module '@stellar/typescript-wallet-sdk/lib/walletSdk/Types'

To work around this issue, I created a custom class resembling AuthToken and used type assertion (as unknown as AuthToken) to proceed. While this approach functions, it doesn't seem optimal.
Could you advise on a more appropriate method to reuse the AuthToken without modifying the existing AuthToken class? Alternatively, how can I resolve the aforementioned error to achieve the desired functionality?
Thank you!
